# How can I make a computer behave as a Bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, htpc

I would like to be able to play music from my computer speakers from my phone using Bluetooth. Is this possible? How do I do it? Can I do this with XBMC?

What I am trying to do is to use my Raspberry Pi / Cu-Box to act like a bridge between Bluetooth and audio cable (RCA / HDMI).

Effectively I want to convert my Raspberry Pi / Cu-Box-i / PC into [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047T79VS) or

[image]

Comment: Does your computer have a Bluetooth device?  Without such a device you can't even do what you describe.

Comment: Yes. my computers do have Bluetooth capabilities.

Comment: What version of Blueetooth.  If either one has Bluetooth LP what you want is unlikely to be possible.

Comment: http://imx.solid-run.com/wiki/index.php?title=CuBox-i_Hardware The CuBox-i has bluetooth 2.1 Is this considered a LP? Will this ( http://www.amazon.com/SoundBot%C2%AE-Bluetooth-Universal-Transmitter-Compatible/dp/B00F25Z0FS )device work?